# How do I connect to Azure SQL from an Azure function using a managed identity (no credentials in connection string)?

Tags: sql-server, authentication, azure-functions, azure-sql-database

I have an Azure Function app, written in C# and using .NET Core (3.x) running on Linux. I would like this set of functions to be able to connect to an Azure SQL database. I have followed this process:

1. I ensured that the function app has system-assigned managed identity enabled:
   [image: system-assigned managed identity is enabled]
2. I created a user in my database using `CREATE USER ... FROM EXTERNAL PROVIDER` and added the user to the appropriate roles (`db_datareader` and `db_datawriter` in my case). In my case, I had to create an Azure AD group and add the managed identity to the group, and then create the user for the group (there were two AD identities with the name of the function app, for some reason...).
3. I set up the connection string in the function app's settings. This is where I think I've gone wrong. I am not clear on how to specify the correct connection string. Connection strings I tried:

   - `Data Source=my-database-server.database.windows.net;Initial Catalog=my-database` did not work. I saw errors such as this: `Login failed for user ''.`
   - `Data Source=my-database-server.database.windows.net;Initial Catalog=my-database;Authentication=Active Directory Integrated` (using `System.Data.SqlClient`) did not work. I saw errors such as this: `Keyword not supported: 'authentication'.`
   - `Data Source=my-database-server.database.windows.net;Initial Catalog=my-database;Authentication=Active Directory Integrated` (using `Microsoft.Data.SqlClient`) I saw errors such as this: `MSAL cannot determine the username (UPN) of the currently logged in user.`

What is the magic connection string incantation, or step that I am missing?

Comment: Are you using EF Core? Could you please show us the code where you establish a connection with the DB?

Comment: At least in EF Core 3.1, you have to add a connection interceptor class to add the access token to the connection before it is opened.

Comment: @KalyanChanumolu-MSFT I'm not using EF Core, but Dapper instead.

Comment: @juunas I assume that looks something like [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-sql/database/authentication-aad-configure?tabs=azure-powershell#azure-ad-token)? Where would I get a token? I would have thought that the entire point of this exercise was to not need to store or pass credentials (like integrated security on Windows would work)?

Comment: Oh you don't need to pass credentials :) You can use DefaultAzureCredential from the Azure.Identity library to get tokens for the managed identity. Just note that the credential does not do caching, you'll need to implement that. Lastly, I'm not sure if Dapper supports AAD authentication, though I'd somehow expect it does..

Comment: @juunas is there any documentation or example code anywhere for that?

Comment: I use this one for EF Core. The token acquisition stuff should work the same for you. https://github.com/juunas11/ElasticDbTenants/blob/76e1b4932ed7332cc2218ce68e423653208df615/ElasticDbTenants.Db.Common/EfAzureAdInterceptor.cs

Answer (score 2):

Use `Microsoft.Data.SqlClient` instead of `System.Data.SqlClient` if getting `Keyword not supported: 'authentication'`

More details on various values for `authentication=` and suppported library versions can be found here:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/ado-net/sql/azure-active-directory-authentication?view=sql-server-ver16#setting-azure-active-directory-authentication

I can't claim any credit for this solution, I found it on reddit of all places!